# Show that if $f $ is $L$-smooth, then $g(x) := f(x) - \frac{m}{2} \Vert x \Vert^2$ is $(L-m)$-smooth

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions, smooth-functions

A continuously differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $L$-smooth if $\nabla f$ is $L$-Lipschitz, i.e., for all $x,y \in \mathbf{dom}\,f$,
$$
\Vert \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \Vert \leq L\Vert x- y \Vert.
$$

Define $g(x) := f(x) - \frac{m}{2} \Vert x \Vert^2$ for some constant $m \geq 0$, and I need to show that $g$ is $(L-m)$-smooth. It seems like a simple enough proof but I keep arriving at an inconclusive result using the triangle inequality: rearrange the equation and we can get $\nabla f(x) = \nabla g(x) + mx$; by substitution, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\Vert \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \Vert &= \Vert \nabla g(x) + mx - \nabla g(y) - my \Vert  \\
&=  \Vert \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y) + m(x-y) \Vert \\
&\leq \Vert \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y)\Vert + m\Vert x-y \Vert, \\
\end{align}
$$
but we don't necessarily have $\Vert \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y)\Vert + m\Vert x-y \Vert \leq L\Vert x- y \Vert$ to finish the proof.

What am I missing here? Any hint is greatly appreciated. The original statement is in [the proof of Proposition 5, p. 13](https://laurentlessard.com/public/siopt16_iqcopt.pdf).

**Update**
It is actually required that $0 < m < L$, but I didn't change this in the original question.

Comment: What if $L<m$, say $f=0$ which is $0$-smooth? Should it be $|L-m|$-smooth?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Do you mean if $f$ maps everything to $0 \in \mathbb{R}$? I suppose you are right, since the original statement didn't mention if $L \leq m$ or $L \geq m$...

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry, it does say that $m \leq L$ on page 3 of the link, the definition of convex functions.

Comment: Is the statement true? If $f$ is $L$-smooth then so is $-f$. So the statement implies that $-f-(m/2)||x||^2$ is $(L-m)$-smooth, but also that $-f+(m/2)||x||^2$ is $(L-m)$-smooth.

Comment: ah, $f$ has to be strongly convex with parameter $m$

Comment: @LinAlg Yeah, the implication in your first comment is true, but yes, $f$ is also $m$-strongly convex, so there's something I'm missing here...

Comment: If $f$ is convex then $-f$ is not convex so the implication isn't useful. You need $m$-strongly convexity in the assumptions or you will not be able to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

As observed $f$ should be m-strongly convex. We start observing that $g(x)=f(x) - \frac{m}{2} \lVert x \rVert^2$ is convex and defined over $\mathbb R^n$. In this case, it is enough to prove the quadratic upper-bound:

$$g(y) \le g(x) + \nabla g(x)^\intercal (y-x) + \frac{1}{2}(L-m) \lVert y-x \rVert^2$$
(for the equivalence see for example Nesterov, Lectures on Convex Optimization, Theorem 2.1.5).

This relation follows from replacing the definition of $g$ in the following inequality for $f$ ($f$ is L-smooth):
$$f(y) \le f(x) + \nabla f(x)^\intercal (y-x) + \frac{1}{2}L \lVert y-x \rVert^2.$$